# Expresso Store error: Error calculating shipping: No rules match the current cart

Tags: expresso-store

I'm using Expresso Store and getting an error message: Error calculating shipping: No rules match the current cart.  Have read the documentation, couldn't find any answers there.  Do I have to link the products to the shipping in some way, or is there something I'm missing out on?

I'm having the problem with a live site and trying to fix this before I put the store live.  I've set up a copy of ExpressionEngine with Store 1.6.1 on my local machine to play around with, but I'm getting the same error.

I've created a Products Channel and linked it to a Channel Field using the Store Product Details Field type. This is what I get when I go to Content > Publish > Products:

I've set up a dummy product as an example.

Then I'm going to Store >  Settings > Shipping Methods.

I've created a Method called Weight and set a rule as shown here:

But unfortunately, I'm getting the above error message.

It's probable something silly I've done, or something small I've missed.

Edit: Screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6oS4.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWen0.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the shipping rules you have created?

Comment: Hi Adrian, I've edit the first comment above to add some links to screenshots of what I've done. These are of a test version I've set up locally, but I'm having the same problem on a live site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store breaks shipping down into two concepts: *Shipping Methods* and *Shipping Rules*. Each Shipping Method has one or more rules.

For example, you might have two shipping methods: *Standard Delivery* and *Express Delivery*. For each of these methods, you would create some rules to calculate shipping costs. Shipping rules can be based on any or all of the following criteria:

- Country
- Region / State
- Postcode / ZIP
- Min & Max Order Quantity
- Min & Max Order Total ($)
- Min & Max Order Weight

When your customer has selected a shipping method, but no rules apply to them to calculate costs from, you will receive the error:

> Error calculating shipping: No rules match the current cart.

There are two ways to fix/avoid this error:

- In most cases, you would create a "catch-all" shipping rule with no criteria, with a shipping price for "everyone else".
- If the shipping method really doesn't apply to this customer (say the shipping method only applies to domestic shipping, but this customer has selected a different country for their shipping address), then you should use a conditional statement in your template so that the customer never sees or selects this payment method.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I should have mentioned that I have created some methods and rules.  I'm trying calculate the shipping costs bsed on the weight of the products.  In my channel entry for the product, I've entered a weight under the Shipping drop down and in Store > Settings > Shipping Methods, I've created a Shipping Method, added a Rule and set filters under Minimum order weight and Maximum Order Weight, but it just dosn't seem to be picking it up. Probable something silly I'm doing, hoping it's something small I've missed.

Comment: Most likely the order is over your max weight, or under your min weight then. Can you edit your question above and detail everything you have set up please (screenshots of shipping settings, and the value of whatever `{order_weight}` outputs in your cart tag.

Comment: Hi Adrian, It's my first time using this so I don't have enough reputation to post images, but I've edited the comment above.  just as an example , in my products channel under the shipping drop down, I've entered 10 for the Weight and in my Store Settings > Shipping Methods Rule I've entered Minimum Order Weight as 7.5 and Maximum Order Weight as 20, but it dosn't seem to be applying the rule.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I've edit the first comment above to add some links to screenshots of what I've done.  These are of a test version I've set up locally, but I'm having the same problem on a live site.